# pushd "no such file or directory" only sometimes

Tags: bash, shell, pushd

**ANSWER**: My problem was that ${DIRSTACK[0]} holds a literal ~, while ${DIRSTACK[@]:1} will not. When I was calling `sort`, I was rearranging the order and then whichever DIRSTACK element ${DIRSTACK[0]} got moved to would not work with pushd +element. I solved this problem by not logging ${DIRSTACK[0]} in my $HOME/.logs/dirstack so that it will never be re-sorted to another index. This bug was reported in [October 2017](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-10/msg00121.html) and will be fixed in some version of bash >4.4.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

So I tried to write a `pushd` function that could 1) remove duplicates from `pushd` (since bash doesn't have `dunique`) and 2) keep the last 10 directories across *all* terminals, meaning I have to write to a file.

```
pd() {
    if [[ -f "$HOME/.logs/dirstack" ]]; then
        dirs -c
        s=($(sort "$HOME/.logs/dirstack" | uniq))
        for dir in "${s[@]}"; do
            pushd -n "$dir" >/dev/null
        done
    fi
    local choice="+$1"
    pushd $choice
    printf '%s\n' "${DIRSTACK[@]:0:10}" >"$HOME/.logs/dirstack"
}
```

So, obviously this function is dumb because with the sorting you really don't know what directory you're `cd`ing into, but this is closer to a Minimum, Viable, Complete Example to show the problem.

**Most** of the time, this function does not work, but sometimes it will. On failure, it displays an error like:

```
j@pc$ pd 2
-bash: pushd: ~/jenkins/docker: No such file or directory
```

On success, it will correctly to go that directory. Failure is *independent* of the particular directory used. All of the directories exist and I can `pushd ~/jenkins/docker` or `cd ~/jenkins/docker` without issue.

Comment: `~/jenkins/docker` is a problem because the `~` is literal; it's looking for a directory with a `~` character in its name.

Comment: ...beyond that, `s=( $( ... ) )` is itself a code smell, since it splits content on all characters in IFS. Any directory with spaces is going to become multiple array entries. And literal newlines are legal in directory names, so you aren't completely safe even if you set `IFS=$'\n'`.

Comment: The MCVE is `cd "~"` which shows `bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory` because `~` is not an actual directory but instead shell syntax. `dirs -l` will show directories with actual directory paths instead of `~`-notation.

Comment: @thatotherguy, but it works sometimes, on file paths that include ~

Comment: @jeremysprofile, very unlikely. Can you provide a reproducer for such a case? `var='~'; cd "$var"` will **always** fail unless you have a directory named `~`; see the linked duplicate.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, ...btw, using `set -x` to enable trace-level logging is likely to be helpful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I'm never quoting ~ or the variable in this. `dirs -v` will show the ~, but `pushd ~` always works. I can get a picture for you? What reproducer would you like?

Comment: @jeremysprofile, if you don't quote the `~` on assignment **when it's entered as a value**, then what's assigned is not the literal value but its expansion result. But if it's part of a command substitution result, then it's never expanded, no matter what the quoting is.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, ...that is to say, `var='~'` behaves identically to `printTilde() { echo '~'; }; var=$(printTilde)`, even though the latter doesn't have quotes (just like your `$(sort ...)` isn't surrounded by quotes).

Comment: @jeremysprofile, ...a textual transcript (maybe copy-and-pasted into an [edit] to the question) taken after running `set -x` would be helpful, yes; ideally, one would show both an operation working, and an operation failing; showing such a transcript of a `cd` to a directory containing a `~` coming from a parameter expansion result would convince me that the dupe flag was incorrect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, sure, 5 minutes

Comment: BTW, replacing `s=( $(sort ...) )` with `readarray -t s < <(sort -u "$HOME/.logs/dirstack")` will at least fix for directory names with spaces, even if it doesn't take care of directory names with newlines (to support those correctly, you'd want to change from a newline-delimited logfile to a NUL-delimited one).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, added

Comment: ...so, `pushd -n` doesn't *actually* try to change directories, so it doesn't report the tilde as a failure, but the first time you actually enact a failure to a stack entry with a literal tilde in it, that fails. That's entirely consistent with the issue the linked duplicate is about.

Comment: notably, you only added one entry with a tilde, and that's the only one that fails.

Comment: (the `pushd +2` output shows tildes in the others, but only the failing one had a tilde present in your input/log file, and thus when `pushd -n` was called).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, looks like you're right. I typed all of them with a tilde, though. Any chance you know why only some of them are converting a tilde to $HOME correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174912/discussion-between-jeremysprofile-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, this bug was reported [October 2017](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-10/msg00121.html). I was kind of excited to get to submit a bug report. Oh well. Thanks for your help.